# Dynamic Column Name for a Derived Column - ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to set a dynamic column name on my query using "select from dual".
Is this possible? If not, kindly recommend alternatives for me to achieve this.
I need this on a normal select query, not by using a stored procedure.

I'm trying to achieve the query below:

```
SELECT  A.NO
        ,A.SUB_NO
        ,A.DCY
        ,A.STATE

        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M1.NUMERATOR),'0') AUG_NUM     --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2),'MON')||'_NUM' FROM DUAL
        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M1.DENOMINATOR),'0') AUG_DEN   --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2),'MON')||'_DEN' FROM DUAL

        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M2.NUMERATOR),'0') JUL_NUM     --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3),'MON')||'_NUM' FROM DUAL
        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M2.DENOMINATOR),'0') JUL_DEN   --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3),'MON')||'_DEN' FROM DUAL

        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M3.NUMERATOR),'0') JUN_NUM     --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-4),'MON')||'_NUM' FROM DUAL
        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M3.DENOMINATOR),'0') JUN_DEN   --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-4),'MON')||'_DEN' FROM DUAL

        ,M1.M1_CALC
        ,M2.M2_CALC
        ,M3.M3_CALC

FROM A, M1,M2,M3;
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Read, for example, [execute immediate 1st](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm), [2nd](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_execute_immediate.htm).

Comment: The problem is that execute immediate requires PL/SQL.

Comment: Are you in Oracle 18c, by any chance?  You could do this with a polymorphic table function, though I really wonder if it'd be worth it.  If you're on 18c, I may write an example for you.  Otherwise, not.  Also, as is often the case with dynamically named columns, you need to question how client programs are going to consume / work with this result set if they don't know the names ahead of time.  Usually, it's better to keep the SQL result columns static and handle renaming in the user interface.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak, I'm on Oracle 10G.

Comment: @JCBA Would it be good enough if you had a normal select query that called a PL/SQL object?  [My open source project](https://github.com/method5/method4) can provide dynamic SQL in SQL, but it requires installing objects first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the closest you're going to get to what you want is by using a `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT NULL no,
       NULL sub_no,
       NULL dcy,
       NULL state,
       TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2),'MON')||'_NUM' AUG_NUM,
       TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2),'MON')||'_DEN' AUG_DEN,
       TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3),'MON')||'_NUM' JUL_NUM,
       TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3),'MON')||'_DEN' JUL_DEN,
       TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-4),'MON')||'_NUM' JUN_NUM,
       TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-4),'MON')||'_DEN' JUN_DEN,
       NULL M1_CAL,
       NULL M2_CALC,
       NULL M3_CALC
FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT  A.NO
        ,A.SUB_NO
        ,A.DCY
        ,A.STATE

        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M1.NUMERATOR),'0') AUG_NUM     --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2),'MON')||'_NUM' FROM DUAL
        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M1.DENOMINATOR),'0') AUG_DEN   --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2),'MON')||'_DEN' FROM DUAL

        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M2.NUMERATOR),'0') JUL_NUM     --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3),'MON')||'_NUM' FROM DUAL
        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M2.DENOMINATOR),'0') JUL_DEN   --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3),'MON')||'_DEN' FROM DUAL

        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M3.NUMERATOR),'0') JUN_NUM     --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-4),'MON')||'_NUM' FROM DUAL
        ,NVL(TO_CHAR(M3.DENOMINATOR),'0') JUN_DEN   --AS SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-4),'MON')||'_DEN' FROM DUAL

        ,M1.M1_CALC
        ,M2.M2_CALC
        ,M3.M3_CALC
FROM A, M1,M2,M3;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried this and saw that it will just insert another row where the desired column name is met.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH A AS
    (
        SELECT  
            636 "NO", 159 "SUB_NO", To_Char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy') "DCY", 'State 1' "STATE"
        FROM dual       --This could be records from any of your data tables
      UNION
        SELECT  
            1272 "NO", 318 "SUB_NO", To_Char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy') "DCY", 'State 2' "STATE"
        FROM dual       --This could be records from any of your data tables
    )
SELECT  
    NO, SUB_NO, DCY, STATE,
    MONTH_MINUS_2_NUM, MONTH_MINUS_2_DEN,
    MONTH_MINUS_3_NUM, MONTH_MINUS_3_DEN,
    MONTH_MINUS_4_NUM, MONTH_MINUS_4_DEN,
    M1_CALC, M2_CALC, M3_CALC
FROM 
    a
MODEL
    DIMENSION BY( DCY, STATE)
    MEASURES( NO, SUB_NO,
              CAST('x' as VarChar2(20)) as MONTH_MINUS_2_NUM, 
              CAST('x' as VarChar2(20)) as MONTH_MINUS_2_DEN,
              CAST('x' as VarChar2(20)) as MONTH_MINUS_3_NUM,
              CAST('x' as VarChar2(20)) as MONTH_MINUS_3_DEN,
              CAST('x' as VarChar2(20)) as MONTH_MINUS_4_NUM,
              CAST('x' as VarChar2(20)) as MONTH_MINUS_4_DEN,
              0 as M1_CALC,
              0 as M2_CALC,
              0 as M3_CALC
             )
    RULES
    (
      MONTH_MINUS_2_NUM[ANY, ANY] = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2),'MON')||'_NUM',
      MONTH_MINUS_2_DEN[ANY, ANY] = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2),'MON')||'_DEN',
      MONTH_MINUS_3_NUM[ANY, ANY] = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3),'MON')||'_NUM',
      MONTH_MINUS_3_DEN[ANY, ANY] = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3),'MON')||'_DEN',
      MONTH_MINUS_4_NUM[ANY, ANY] = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-4),'MON')||'_NUM',
      MONTH_MINUS_4_DEN[ANY, ANY] = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-4),'MON')||'_DEN',
  -- Dynamic Calculations -> you can calculate prety much anything you want
      M1_CALC[2022, 'State 1'] = NO[CV(), CV()] / 2,
      M2_CALC[2022, 'State 1'] = NO[CV(), CV()] / 3,
      M3_CALC[2022, 'State 1'] = NO[CV(), CV()] / 4,
      M1_CALC[2022, 'State 2'] = NO[CV(), CV()] / 2,
      M2_CALC[2022, 'State 2'] = NO[CV(), CV()] / 3,
      M3_CALC[2022, 'State 2'] = NO[CV(), CV()] / 4
    )
```

Comment: Don't know what you are trying to calculate, but whatever it is it could probably be solved using MODEL clause. It is a bit tricky in the begining but very rewarding later. More info at https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm